# Prove this inequality by math induction

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} k^p < \frac{ n^{p+1}}{p+1} < \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^p $$

I know how to prove it by using Riemann Sum, but it I was thinking if there is anyway to do it by mathematical induction?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to prove that:
$$\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}+n^p < \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}\tag{1}$$
and:
$$\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}+(n+1)^p > \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}\tag{2}$$
or:
$$(n+1)^{p+1}>n^{p+1}+(p+1)n^p\tag{1*}$$
$$n^{p+1}+p(n+1)^p > 0\tag{2*}$$
where $(1*)$ follows from the binomial theorem and $(2*)$ is trivial.